# Add a picture in a MKAnnotationView inside the title

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I was searching for any lib that allows me to do this:

[1 http://zsoft.es/imgs/annotations.jpg](http://zsoft.es/imgs/annotations.jpg)

And the possibly to add a button in the right part in the title, also if possible adding more images in the subtitle or the button in the subtitle...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKAnnotationView/leftCalloutAccessoryView) use `leftCalloutAccessoryView`:

In `(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation`

You can assign a `UIImageView` to the `leftCalloutAccessoryView`:

```
myAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]
```

Comment: In that case I only can assign 1 thing in each CalloutAccessoryView, right? or I can make another UIView with my things and finally assign in the leftCalloutAccesoryView? Then I have another question, the "bubble" will redimensionated if I put a image 100x100 px? Thanks

Comment: yes, each CalloutAccessoryView can only reference one view. I believe your image will be resized as there is a maximum size (32 pixels according to the linked doc); it is quite restrictive on what you can put in there - have a play around and try it.

Comment: Ok, thanks =) I realized that my IMG is not resized so... but I appreciate your help very much, as the other answer. Thanks everybody =)

Comment: I mean, is resized the width to a max. but height none xD.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the following properties on the MKAnnotationView.

```
// The left accessory view to be used in the standard callout.
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIView *leftCalloutAccessoryView;

// The right accessory view to be used in the standard callout.
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIView *rightCalloutAccessoryView;
```

Comment: Do I have to implement that in the MKAnnotation delegated classS? I have a custom class fot MKAnnotation that has title, subtitle and coordinate. I have to add title and subtitle in the RightCalloutAccessoryView and a UIImage in leftCallOutAccessoryView right?, or?